# CSS specificity rule trouble

Tags: css

I have this two styles in CSS, both in an external linked css file, and applied to the same table, with class myTable (it's a simplified version of a larger problem):

```
.myTable th
{
    background-color: gray;
}

.myTable tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

When I run the page, the header is gray, but why? What I want to know is why the first rule is overwriting the second. If I understood well specificity calculations (and obviously I didn't) the second rule is more specific (all calculators give me 0, 1, 2 in the second rule and 0, 1, 1 in the first one). Why then, the header is gray and not blue, if the second rule has more specificity???? Could someone help me understand this, please? Thank you very very much...

Comment: Did you understand now?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `th` or `td`:

```css
.myTable tr:nth-child(odd) th,
.myTable tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Because you are applying for `th` in your first class, you need to use that here. The `th` is inside the `tr`, so whatever you put, `th` will be in front showing the grey colour.

Answer (score 1):

CSS specificity does not apply in your situation.

Your CSS targets two different elements; `th` and `tr`.

You have to think about this from a **layer** perspective.

Because `th`'s are contained in `tr`'s then the `background-color` of the `th` will be displayed *above* the `background-color` of the `tr`.

Take this code for example:

```
<tr style="background-color: gray">
    <th>Heading One</th>
    <th style="background-color: red">Heading Two</th>
    <th>Heading Three</th>
</tr>
```

The first and third `th` have a *transparent* `background-color`, so the `background-color` of the `tr` shows through them. The second `th` has a `background-color` defined so it shows as expected.

You can take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/bhan0fuk/2/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule is not overwriting the second rule.

The reason is that your header is grey is because it contains `th` elements, and you only specified `background: grey` for the `th` elements.  (And a `th` is not the same as a `tr`).

If you want alternating column colors in your header also, then modify your code to address *both* the `th` and the `td`, like so:

```
.myTable th {
    background-color: gray;
}

.myTable td:nth-child(odd),
.myTable th:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks... I put a transparent color (rgba) to the header and I saw the blue color behind, so it means that CSS was painting the header "over" the tr... thank you very much...

Comment: @AlanEspinet did you see my answer?